# What does the Fusion360 client app do?

Tags: fusion360

I have a beginner question: Tinkercad is a fully cloud based and the STL files are/can be stored locally on our computer (STL files are not stored in the cloud).
Fusion 360 is also fully cloud-based. However, I installed a Fusion360 client app on my pc. Is the app I downloaded just a client that communicates with the actual Fusion360 software via the internet connection?

Could I use Fusion360 without downloading that app and just via the browser as we do with Tinkercad? I feel like the client app on my computer I downloaded is quite slow.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use Fusion 360 via the browser without downloading. You just need Autodesk account.
Here is the [link](https://fusion.online.autodesk.com/).

However, if your computer was too slow for desktop app, you might also have problems via the browser.

Comment: Very well. I assume the Fusion360 client has some advantages compared to using Fusion360 only via the browser...

Comment: Just tried the web version and it wouldn't let me use it because I have to have an education account. The client software, however, is still free for now even for non-students.